# Magento How to link to category by id from static block/page

Tags: magento, categories, static-block

I'm looking to link to a category from a static block using the `category id`. Any thoughts?

I've done the usual searches, but to no avail.

At the moment I can do something like `<a href="{{store url="category-i-want.html"}}">`, but this is hardly robust.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the category link widget inline link code:

```
{{widget type="catalog/category_widget_link" anchor_text="Displayed Text" title="Title attribute text" template="catalog/category/widget/link/link_block.phtml" id_path="category/22"}}
```

Comment: THanks Ben. Perfect and swift!

Comment: I have used this code it is working.  When I cleared the cache in admin, the link loads different category products but the url shows correct for the first time.  What is the cause of the issue?

Comment: How can I add a class tag to the generated anchor element?