# How to get store category url in Magento 1.8?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

how can I get the store **category url**?

I know I can get the store direct url like this,

```
<a href="{{store direct_url="contacts"}}">Contact Us</a>
```

But what about the store's categories?

The categories I have in my store, such as 'Wines', 'Food', etc, so if I do this,

```
{{store direct_url="wines"}} // returns http://mystore/wine
```

I will get a 404 error page. Because the url should be like this,

`http://mystore/wine.html`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try category link widget:

```
{{widget type="catalog/category_widget_link" anchor_text="Displayed Text" title="Title attribute text" template="catalog/category/widget/link/link_block.phtml" id_path="category/22"}}
```

Reference from [Magento How to link to category by id from static block/page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317719/magento-how-to-link-to-category-by-id-from-static-block-page)